# is there any way to copy double type arrays

Tags: c, arrays

how can i copy a double type array into an another double type array in c

here is a part of code:

```
int main(int argc, chae *argv[]){
  double *a, *b;
  int n = 20;
  a = (double *)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
  a = (double *)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++ ){
    a[i] =drand48();
  }
}
```

but without using a loop like the following

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++ ){
   b[i] = a[i];
}
```

is there any function to do this automatically

Comment: Are you looking for [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy)?

Comment: For the second `malloc` call, do you mean to assign the pointer to `b` instead of assigning to `a` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to copy arrays in C directly.

You have two options:

1. The loop you mentioned:

   ```
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       b[i] = a[i];
   }
   ```
2. The `memcpy` function:

   ```
   memcpy(b, a, n * sizeof(double));
   ```

Comment: Note that these options are equivalent and the compiler may (and probably will) generate the same assembly for both, when optimization is enabled

Answer (score -3):

The solution you are looking for is `memcpy(void*,void*,size_t)`

```
memcpy(&Array1[0], &Array2[0], sizeof(Array1));
```

In C language , typecast from standard pointer types to void * is done implicitly by the compiler. So no need to worry about passing double pointer as argument.

Comment: You definitely do *not* want to divide by `sizeof(double)` there.

Comment: Why is it ?  Can you Explain?

Comment: `sizeof(Array1)` reports the size in bytes.  `memcpy` wants the size in bytes.  You need to divide *if* you want a count of the elements.  That's often what you want, which is why you often see the division -- but this is one place where you do *not* want the division.